# WalletConnect on frontend not working

Tags: wallets, dapps, walletconnect

I want to add wallet connect on my website. I try to do it like Metamask (i.e : adding web3.js in my HTML file and write script to interact with user). But this tutorial is not working :

https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal-vanilla-js-example/
This is the error :

```
POSThttps://mainnet.infura.io/v3/8043bb2cf99347b1bfadfb233c5325c0
[HTTP/2 403 Forbidden 99ms]
```

What can I do ? Change infura ID for mine ?

Comment: This is just a guess, but did you import the libraries correctly in your HTML using script tags? Did you explicitly set up web3 to use walletconnect? The only thing I can see is that perhaps web3 is connecting to a default provider (infura) rather than to walletconnect, and at the same there is some problem with the infura provider. I could be wrong though.

Comment: This error occur on the hosted github page to show the project here : https://web3modal.github.io/web3modal-vanilla-js-example/ so the example isn't working correctly, I can use it to my project

Comment: The example site seems to not be working for me, so yes maybe it's a problem with their code. Unfortunately I've never used walletconnect API yet so can't help you out with that right now.

Comment: When you click on the button, then when you click on "walletconnect" a QrCode must pop up but nothing happens (it's the only feature that I want to do)

Comment: Yeah I scanned the QR code with my MetaMask wallet and the website said "not connected", I'm not sure why.